# Division of vectors if they are scaled version of each other.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know in general division of vectors is not defined. If $A= cB$ for $A,B$ vectors, then I don't understand why we cannot write $c=A/B$.

Comment: If you add some extra algebra rules it could be possible, but then it is not called a vector anymore. I think Clifford algebra can have inverses like that. Pretty sure matrix algebra has it too. Might be that you have to differentiate between left and right inverses in those cases.

Comment: What would 1/B mean? If you cannot give meaning to it then what might A(1/B) mean?

Comment: I am not trying to generalise it . I am just asking whether A vector/ B vector= c makes sense.

Comment: You should look up the axioms ofa vector space. There is no division defined in them.

Comment: In fact you are implicitly generaliizing it, because you are suggesting that there is a thing called vector division and this is an example of it. If you then say "but I never said that there is a thing called vector division" then we must conclude that A/B means nothing. No?

Comment: As another similar example, just because 0(3) = 0 can we conclude that 3 = 0/0? We can if we say that 0/0 means 3. The problem with this is that division by 0 is not defined, we have created a division example without first defining what division by 0 means.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because it can't be generalized to other vectors. You're saying that

[aX,aY] / [X,Y] = a

But what if X and Y aren't scaled by the same factor? What is

[aX,bY] / [X,Y] = ?

It would be hard to create a whole new definition and find important uses for it. It's just not necessary to be able to write A=cB in a different order.

Comment: But is it wrong to write A vector/B vector = c

Comment: Yes, because vector division is simply not defined. No one will know what you mean.